# In Scala converting Int to Double using asInstanceOf. Yet the variable cannot be casted

Tags: scala

I am using this function in Scala to multiply each element of list with 100. But when trying to type cast percent val it is giving me error.

```
  def func[T](listOne: List[T])(implicit numeric: Numeric[T]): List[T] = {
    import numeric._
    val percent = 100.asInstanceOf[T]
    listOne.map { e => e * percent }
  }
```

This is the ScalaTest written using FlatSpec and Matchers. The first test runs successfully but the second test fails due to Double data type of List but the percent data type still being Int .

```
  "func" should "return Int list multiplied by 100" in {
    func(list1) should be (List(100, 200))
  }
  it should "return Double list multiplied by 100" in {
    func(list2) should be (List(150, 210))
  }
```

The Exception given is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Comment: That always produces `"Double"`.

Comment: The output is double

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yet the data type being printed is Int. Can you tell a method to convert in to Double.

Comment: @AbhishekRathore I just tried it a number of times in 2.12.4. It always prints `"Double"`. I ran exactly the code shown and only that.

Comment: @AbhishekRathore Are you by any chance using Scala.js? In Scala.js this snippet would indeed display `Int`, but in Scala/JVM it would display `Double`.

Comment: You have edited it into a new and different question. Now all the previous comments and answers are meaningless. That's not how things are done on SO.

Comment: @jwvh That was the problem I was facing and due to the description I had given, it was not clear for the users. So, I edited and provide some better code with test so that the question is answered in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine for me in the REPL

[image]

And the `getClass` method of x returns `Double`

[image]

Anyway, the proper and easiest way to convert and `Int` to a `Double`
is `.toDouble`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the preferred way to convert Ints to Doubles is to use the [`Int.toDouble`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Int.html#toDouble) method. The `asInstanceOf[]` method is intended for up-casting between generations in a class hierarchy. `Int` and `Double` to not have such a parent-child relationship (although will have a common parent in `AnyVal`).